# How to correctly code a recursive jquery promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Pardon me if I'm repeating an already very asked question but everything I have seen so far doesn't seem recursive to me, or doesn't map to what we are doing, and the subject of promises and deferred seems to be highly complex for me.

I have a "topic tree" that gets built asynchronously as the user expands nodes. This topic is built using an API endpoint that returns the children of a node on click of the (+) button on the topic tree node.

When the user clicks on button I try to recursively load the topic tree elements using a method that looks like this:

```
function getAssociatedTopics(){
    $.get('/topics/curriculum-associations', {guids: [...]})
    .then(function(data){

        //Process the topic information here
        var topicId = /* some processing */;

        //Get ancestors of each topic returned
        $.get('/topics/getAncestors', {of: topicId})
        .then(function(data){

            //Process the topic information here
            var topicId = /* some processing */;

            //Get ancestors of each topic returned
            //Rinse repeat as long as we find children of each topic found


        });

    }).then(function(){

        //Expand the nodes
        //Select the nodes

    });
}
```

So this is what it should look like but I'm all lost reading the documentation to make sure my stuff executes in the right order... The big problem we are having right now with this structure is that my nodes all load in a concurrent way and then erase the selected nodes, open and close nodes any time and the selection ends up super messy.

I don't want an in depth explanation of promises, nor do I want a full solution, but a general idea how to achieve this.

Comment: You want to expand the node subtree? Or just the first childs?

Comment: You say "when the user clicks on button", is this button the `(+)` button on the topic tree node, or some other button? Because you *say* you have "an API endpoint that returns the children of a node" but you have not shown anything which clearly does that yet (unless that's what `/topics/curriculum-associations` does).

Comment: Also, the code says *Get ancestors of each topic returned*, which leads me to believe there's a loop we're not seeing. A loop which could very well determine the correctness of the answer...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "expanding nodes"? Loading immediate children of the clicked node, or expanding whole tree of all nodes? If you mean the former, then why do you need recursive load?

Comment: Confusing, you're sure you're not trying to do something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/st5fz0h1/

Comment: Just another instance of ["ask-and-run" questioner](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256788/dealing-with-ask-and-run-questioners)

Comment: from your question, it isn't clear what the `$.get()` API calls do. You have two separate API calls that have identical code following them. Your question is not simple because it appears not that you not only asynchronously fetch ancestors, but also asynchronously process results.

Comment: @hindmost it's not about them, it's about the other people facing the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, The complexity of fetching what you need should be handled on the server and not the client. Making hundreds of HTTP requests from the client is a performance disaster waiting to happen.

Now for how you'd do it, two important facts:

- Promises work by using the *return value*. `$.get` returns a promise for the value - that's why you can `then` off it, but you can also return it to the outside.
- If you return a promise from a `then` handler, the promise returns from the `then` itself will wait for the inner promise to resolve first.

Here is an example illustrating the two points:

```
$.get("/api").then(function(data) {
    return $.get("/api2/" + data.id);
}).then(function(data2) {
    // because of point #1, we get the data of the inner call here.
});
```

Now, for your actual problem:

```
function getAssociatedTopics(guids) {
    // note the `return` here so it can be chained from outside 
    return $.get('/topics/curriculum-associations', {guids: guids})
    .then(function(data){
        var topicId = someProcessing(data);
        // note we return here. I assume this get returns guids. 
        return $.get('/topics/getAncestors', {of: topicId})
    }).then(function (guids) { // this anonymous function can be inlined
        if(guids.length === 0) return; // stop condition
        return getAssociatedTopics(guids); // note the recursive call, remember point #2.
    });
}
getAssociatedTopics(initial).then(function(){
    // all done
});
```

If you need the results of all the calls, you can chain it off, or you can push to a closure variable array inside the then before the last and access it in the all done handler.